# Create hidden folder with it's own password to open?

Tags: nautilus, password

In Ubuntu 22.04 is it possible to have password protected gates to hidden folders within the file manager?

Comment: Please don't ask questions that ask for a yes or no answer.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/645782/how-to-password-protect-a-hidden-directory or https://askubuntu.com/questions/613517/is-there-a-way-i-can-password-protect-a-folder-without-encrypting-compressing

Comment: I guess I should have asked for a simple way to password protect a hidden folder. After reading the links and their links, it seems that the only way to do it is with encryption. That looks too complicated for me. Thanks to everyone for finding that information for me. Maybe sometime in the future I'll feel capable of using it.